# CodeIgniter with PHP Activerecord Spark Multiple Databases

Tags: php, codeigniter, database-connection, phpactiverecord

So far I really enjoy how CodeIgniter plays together with PHP ActiveRecord ORM tool,

How would I go about specifying which connection to use in my models?

My config/database.php file has 2 connections set up: `$db['default']` and `$db['myOtherDb']`

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UPDATE:

I found my solution by invoking the autocomplete in my IDE inside my ActiveRecord Model and checking the available methods/properties, one of the properties is `$connection` and we can set it to the connection that we want to use, so in my model:

```
public static $connection = 'byOtherDb';
```

Answer (score 0):

Inside the controller you can add :

```
var $db_1, $db_2;
function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();

    $db1_param = 'mysql://database_username:password@localhost/database_name?char_set=utf8&dbcollat=utf8_general_ci';
    $db2_param = 'mysql://database_username:password@localhost/database_name?char_set=utf8&dbcollat=utf8_general_ci';

    $this->db_1 = $this->load->database($db1_param, TRUE);
    $this->db_2 = $this->load->database($db2_param, TRUE);
}
```

then your handlers are : $this->db_1 , $this->db_2

Comment: I know this way to do it when using native CI DB implementation. Does that apply to PHP ActiveRecord Spark?

Comment: As long as your Config is setup to allow active record, then this is the same as doing `$this->load->database()` without any parameters (i.e. default database)

Comment: In PHP ActiveRecord models I don't refer to db as $this->db, but simply call PHP ActiveRecord methods (like create, find_by_sql etc), so my sample method is:
`public function getRequestsAndComments()
{
    $query   = "SELECT * FROM request;
    $results = self::find_by_sql($query);
    
    return $results;
}`

Answer (score 0):

Specify the new db name in the `load->database` function,

```
$otherdb = $this->load->database('myotherdb', TRUE);
```

[Refer this for more info](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/connecting.html)

Comment: I know this way to do it when using native CI DB implementation. Does that apply to PHP ActiveRecord Spark?